# display form and query result on the same page

Tags: php, forms

I know that this theme has been arround for a long time. But, what I want is to display a form and display the result of the request below, on the same page **without** erasing (reseting) the form.

So, always display the form, empty at first, and then always diplaying what the user has input. And then display the result of the request below the form.

I have tried to manipulate the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) stament but it either show the result on the top and not below and it reset the form value.

Answer (score 0):

can you show us the Code, 2ndly its also possible via ajax

Answer (score 0):

It's calling ajax call.

First of all you need three page for this (actually you can do that with one page but it seems not good.)

1. Show page: index.php Which have form and result div.
2. Ajax call script: main.js which is included in index.php with  tag.
3. Service: service.php which is return to you data.